# How to search multiple tables in database?

Tags: sql

I am new to sql and I need to search multiple tables in database and return their fname, lname, rname, their advisor name, and social media address but right now when I run my code I get the same name outputted multiple times and also some names do not have advisors so the output should be null yet in the table it put a name in the advisor field.

```
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------------+---------+----------+
| idnum | lname   | fname    | rname                   | private | linkblue |
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------------+---------+----------+
| 22222 | Clemens | Timothy  | clemens.timothy@uky.edu |       0 | tgcl258  |
| 40256 | South   | William  | south.william@uky.edu   |       1 | weso123  |
| 55555 | North   | Dan      | north.dan@uky.edu       |       0 | ddno453  |
| 56732 | Cox     | Courtney | NULL                    |       1 | cco546   |
| 68123 | Smith   | Terry    | smith.terry@uky.edu     |       1 | tlsm321  |
+-------+---------+----------+-------------------------+---------+----------+

+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+-------+
| student | advisor | student_name  | advisor_name  | sdate | edate |
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+-------+
|   40256 |   40256 | William South | Abby Tanner   | NULL  | NULL  |
|   68123 |   68123 | Terry Smith   | Nicole Taylor | NULL  | NULL  |
+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+-------+-------+

+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| idnum | smtype   | smaddr                       |
+-------+----------+------------------------------+
| 22222 | facebook | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| 40256 | facebook | facebook.com/south.william   |
| 68123 | facebook | facebook.com/smith.terry     |
| 22222 | twitter  | twitter.com/clemons.timothy  |
| 40256 | twitter  | twitter.com/south.william    |
| 68123 | twitter  | twitter.com/smith.terry      |
+-------+----------+------------------------------+
```

Partial Output:

```
+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
| fname    | lname   | rname                   | advisor_name  | smaddr                       |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------+------------------------------+
| Timothy  | Clemens | clemens.timothy@uky.edu | Abby Tanner   | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| Timothy  | Clemens | clemens.timothy@uky.edu | Nicole Taylor | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| William  | South   | south.william@uky.edu   | Abby Tanner   | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| William  | South   | south.william@uky.edu   | Nicole Taylor | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| Dan      | North   | north.dan@uky.edu       | Abby Tanner   | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| Dan      | North   | north.dan@uky.edu       | Nicole Taylor | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| Courtney | Cox     | NULL                    | Abby Tanner   | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| Courtney | Cox     | NULL                    | Nicole Taylor | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| Terry    | Smith   | smith.terry@uky.edu     | Abby Tanner   | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| Terry    | Smith   | smith.terry@uky.edu     | Nicole Taylor | facebook.com/clemons.timothy |
| Timothy  | Clemens | clemens.timothy@uky.edu | Abby Tanner   | facebook.com/south.william   |
| Timothy  | Clemens | clemens.timothy@uky.edu | Nicole Taylor | facebook.com/south.william   |
| William  | South   | south.william@uky.edu   | Abby Tanner   | facebook.com/south.william   |
```

Code:

```
SELECT fname, lname, rname, advisor_name, smaddr FROM PERSON, ADVISOR, DIGITAL;
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

from your query, you are selecting each column from the table. the best to explain this is, we can say you are concatenating the three  table. you should add a where condition to prevent the null and duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? 
One odd thing in your data is that student and advisor values in ADVISOR table are same.

```
SELECT P.fname, P.lname, P.rname, A.advisor_name, D.smaddr FROM 
  PERSON P
  LEFT JOIN  ADVISOR A 
  on P.idnum = A.student
  LEFT JOIN DIGITAL D
  on P.idnum = D.idnum;
```